# how to stop activemq failover reconnect process

Tags: activemq-classic, shutdown, failover, reconnect

I use ActiveMQ Client 5.10.0 and failover protocol to connect to ActiveMQ Node,what I face now is that the failover reconnect process executes indefinitely if the ActiveMQ Node used in the failover uri breaks up,and another thread which is intended to stop the reconnect process just waits.
The thread dump which belongs to the mentioned stop thread above is as follows:

I can not post the whole thread dump here,please get from the [link](http://blog.csdn.net/dslztx/article/details/51441213)

could anyone help me?I am stuck in this problem for a long time!
Thanks very much!

By the way,I can not use any newer versions of ActiveMQ Client，because the target environment JDK is 1.6

Comment: Not enough to go on here, need the stack trace from the thread holding the lock this one is waiting for.

Comment: I upload the whole thread dump,thanks for reply